# History of Neural Networks and Deep Learning

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, reference-request, history

I'm interested in learning about the history of neural networks and deep learning. I've been reading about the field and am familiar with many of the developments since the 1950s.  Is there a textbook, video, or blog post that comprehensively covers the developments in this field from the 1950s to the present day?